# How do I build PortAudio on Mac?

Tags: macos, build, pyaudio, portaudio

I did brew install portaudio, and it is in `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/portaudio/19.7.0`.
I'm trying to use PyAudio and speech_recognition, and apparently, I need to build portaudio. I tried `./configure && make` in the portaudio directory, and it says, `zsh: no such file or directory: ./configure`. I'm stuck here.